# Check if a value is within a range of numbers

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to check if a value is in an accepted range. If yes, to do something; otherwise, something else.

The range is `0.001-0.009`. I know how to use multiple `if` to check this, but I want to know if there is any way to check it in a single `if` statement.

Answer (score 343, accepted):

You're asking a question about numeric comparisons, so regular expressions really have nothing to do with the issue.  You don't need "multiple `if`" statements to do it, either:

```
if (x >= 0.001 && x <= 0.009) {
  // something
}
```

You could write yourself a "between()" function:

```
function between(x, min, max) {
  return x >= min && x <= max;
}
// ...
if (between(x, 0.001, 0.009)) {
  // something
}
```

Answer (score 80):

Here is an option with only a single comparison.

```
// return true if in range, otherwise false
function inRange(x, min, max) {
    return ((x-min)*(x-max) <= 0);
}

console.log(inRange(5, 1, 10));     // true
console.log(inRange(-5, 1, 10));    // false
console.log(inRange(20, 1, 10));    // false
```

Comment: This is sweet it doesn't matter if min is lower or max is lower it will still work. In fact it might be better to call min, max something like start, end. great algo either way thanks!

Comment: Won't somebody PLEASE think of the time complexity!? I'd go with the accepted solution because two comparisons at Θ(2) is better than one comparison and three arithmetic operations at O(4).

Comment: I never claimed it to be whatever you imagined yourself it is. It is a viable option, nevertheless.

Comment: This is a little silly, it's not only probably slower but also much less obvious as to what the code does

Answer (score 22):

If you *must* use a regexp (and really, you shouldn't!) this will work:

```
/^0\.00([1-8]\d*|90*)$/
```

should work, i.e.

- `^` nothing before,
- followed by `0.00` (nb: backslash escape for the `.` character)
- followed by 1 through 8, and any number of additional digits
- or 9, followed by any number of zeroes
- `$`: followed by nothing else

Answer (score 20):

If you're already using `lodash`, you could use the `inRange()` function:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#inRange

```js
_.inRange(3, 2, 4);
// => true

_.inRange(4, 8);
// => true

_.inRange(4, 2);
// => false

_.inRange(2, 2);
// => false

_.inRange(1.2, 2);
// => true

_.inRange(5.2, 4);
// => false

_.inRange(-3, -2, -6);
// => true
```

Answer (score 4):

I like Pointy's `between` function so I wrote a similar one that worked well for my scenario.

```
/**
 * Checks if an integer is within ±x another integer.
 * @param {int} op - The integer in question
 * @param {int} target - The integer to compare to
 * @param {int} range - the range ±
 */
function nearInt(op, target, range) {
    return op < target + range && op > target - range;
}
```

so if you wanted to see if `x` was within ±10 of `y`:

```
var x = 100;
var y = 115;
nearInt(x,y,10) = false
```

I'm using it for detecting a long-press on mobile:

```
//make sure they haven't moved too much during long press.
if (!nearInt(Last.x,Start.x,5) || !nearInt(Last.y, Start.y,5)) clearTimeout(t);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want your code to pick a specific range of digits, be sure to use the `&&` operator instead of the `||`.

```js
if (x >= 4 && x <= 9) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}

// be sure not to do this

if (x >= 4 || x <= 9) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You must want to determine the lower and upper bound before writing the condition

```
function between(value,first,last) {

 let lower = Math.min(first,last) , upper = Math.max(first,last);
 return value >= lower &&  value <= upper ;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`const inRange = (num, num1, num2) => Math.min(num1, num2) <= num && Math.max(num1, num2) >= num;`

Could be like this if you want to make inRange inclusive and not depend on order of range numbers (num1, num2).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short ES6 function:

```js
const inRange = (num, min, max) => num >= min && num <= max
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isInRange(number, min, max) {
    return number >= min && number <= max;
}

// Example usage:
console.log(isInRange(5, 1, 10));   // Output: true
console.log(isInRange(15, 1, 10));  // Output: false
console.log(isInRange(-5, -10, 0)); // Output: true
```

**Example 2**

```
function isWithinRange(value, range) {
    return value >= range[0] && value <= range[1];
}

// Example usage:
console.log(isWithinRange(5, [1, 10]));   // Output: true
console.log(isWithinRange(15, [1, 10]));  // Output: false
console.log(isWithinRange(-5, [-10, 0])); // Output: true
```