# Can javascript generate executable javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keycode

This is a sample javascript code to alert the user if he clicks shift + 1 (or 2,3...9)

But as you see this code is almost the same.

```
a = window.event.keyCode;

var b = window.event.shiftKey

if (a == 49 && b) {
    alert(document.getElementById('alert1').length)
}
if (a == 50 && b) {
    alert(document.getElementById('alert2').length)
}
if (a == 51 && b) {
    alert(document.getElementById('alert3').length)
}
if (a == 52 && b) {
    alert(document.getElementById('alert4').length)
}
if (a == 53 && b) {
    alert(document.getElementById('alert5').length)
}
if (a == 54 && b) {
    alert(document.getElementById('alert6').length)
}
if (a == 55 && b) {
    alert(document.getElementById('alert7').length)
}
if (a == 56 && b) {
    alert(document.getElementById('alert8').length)
}
if (a == 57 && b) {
    alert(document.getElementById('alert9').length)
}
```

Is there any javascript (it can be jQuery) code (using `for(){}` method or something else) that will do the same job by writing less code and the other code to be generated by the browser and executed when is required?

Comment: `'alertX'` are all strings. You can create then dynamically from the value of `a`. Give it a go.

Comment: So? It's still a variable. Do what you want with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript - check a range of numbers in if statement with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454198/javascript-check-a-range-of-numbers-in-if-statement-with-regex)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not create executable Javascript but review your code.

Repetitive code can most times be written as a loop or in your case by math.

```
if(a < 58 && a > 48 && b) {
  alert(document.getElementById('alert'+(a-48)).length)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't really want code generation + execution, that can get pretty dangerous.

All you need is a little [DRY](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself)ing of your code:

```
var ALERT_KEYCODE_OFFSET = 48;
var alertIndex, alertId;
if (a >= 49 && a <= 57 && b)
{
    alertIndex = a - ALERT_KEYCODE_OFFSET;
    alertId = 'alert' + alertIndex;
    alert(document.getElementById(alertId).length);
}
```

Comment: Using `var` in `if` makes me cry. It makes following the scope of variables much more tedious.

Comment: So it's less tedious if everything's just global?  OK.  Is there a special scoping rule for "if" that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Eh @PaulS., my bad.  Now I know things.  I hate you JavaScript.  For those who don't know, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Comment: I mean it's less tedious if you set the `var` before the `if`, not inside it. `if` blocks don't have their own scope unless you can use JavaScript 1.7's `let`, any `var` gets hoisted upwards to the beginning of the scope. This means if you're trying to find if/which scope a `var` is declared, it can get confusing if written like this. EDIT Yup, non-block-scoping is one of the many quirks of JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, I had this foolish idea that there was such a thing as block scope for `var` (without using `let`).  I mean, it _looks_ like it should.  Thanks for showing me otherwise!