# How to see if number is "between" values?

Tags: javascript

// beginner learning Js in a program I was asked to start work on a Rock, Paper, Scissors game
this is the code I made, but the computer always choses scissors!? any idea why?
any help would be awesome!

1. If computerChoice is between 0 and 0.33, make computerChoice equal to "rock".
2. If computerChoice is between 0.34 and 0.66, make computerChoice equal to "paper".
3. If computerChoice is between 0.67 and 1, make computerChoice equal to "scissors".

```
var userChoice = prompt ("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice === (0 , 0.33)) {
    console.log("rock");
} else if (computerChoice === (0.34 , 0.66)) {
    console.log("paper");
} else {
    console.log("scissors");
}
```

Comment: Languages tend to work best when you don't make up your own syntax, and expect it to work. Where did you come up with `computerChoice === (0 , 0.33)`?

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454198/javascript-check-a-range-of-numbers-in-if-statement  (I used up all of my close votes).

Comment: Would this help simplify what you're checking against? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range

Set the range to 1 - 3 and check against that..

Comment: Aren't you supposed to ask on codecademy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, you can't just make up syntax - it Just Doesn't Work. Programming is about the application of [existing rules](http://es5.github.io/), where most rules are not your own.

In JavaScript, due to the [comma-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579546/comma-operator-where-it-can-really-be-useful), `x === (a, b)` is semantically equivalent to `x === b` (when the `a` expression has no side-effects), so that clearly won't work. In the original code this ensured that none of the first two conditions (e.g `choice === 0.33`) ever matched - so the default/else of "scissors" was always chosen.

While [the general way to check an inclusive range is `x >= a && x <= b`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454198/check-a-range-of-numbers-in-an-if-condition), we can do one better than this by relying on the ordering of `if` conditional evaluation and ["inchworming"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inchworm) through an expanding range.

```
if (choice <= 1/3) {
  console.log("rock");
} else if (choice <= 2/3) { /* choice > 1/3, per above */
  console.log("paper");
} else {                    /* choice > 2/3, per above */
  console.log("scissors");
}
```

Alternatively, we could also get a discreet random *integer* back,

```
/* get a random number 1, 2, or 3 */
var choice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
```

and then direct equality without a range check can be used

```
if (choice === 1) {
  console.log("rock");
} else if (choice === 2) {
  console.log("paper");
} else { /* choice === 3 */
  console.log("scissors");
}
```

Comment: +1: Good explanation of what's going on, and good catch on the (pointless) validity of `(0, 0.33)`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using valid JavaScript syntax for numeric comparison.  There is no structure in JavaScript that allows you to do this:

```
if(computerChoice===(0, 0.33)){
    //...
}
```

Try this instead:

```
if(computerChoice > 0 && computerChoice <= 0.33){
    //...
}
```

Comment: Devil's advocate: JavaScript *does* allow the first syntax .. it just doesn't, uhh, have the "between" behavior.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but CoffeeScript would allow `if 0 < computerChoice < 0.33`.

Comment: @Seiyria That's cool. It looks like it uses similar expansion rules to Python (which also allows this sort of conditional chaining): `1 < x < 2` (CS) is percolated to `1 < x && x < 2` (JS).

Comment: Good point, @user2865740.  Allowed, in this case, however, does not equal useful.  `(0, 0.33)` will simply evaluate to `0.33`, making this statement completely pointless.  But your point is taken!