# check if number is inside the range or beyond the range

Tags: javascript

i have an a range number coming from server as below.

```
var max = 50;
var min = 25;
var uservalue = document.getElementById("userinput").value;// 35
```

User enters value in input box and i need to compare if entered value is inside the range or above the range.
I have written code as below but not working.

```
if(uservalue<min || uservalue>max ){
alert("Error");
}else if (uservalue>min && uservalue<max)
alert("success");
```

What is the recommended conditions to see if user entered value is inside the rang or outside the range
EDIT: user enters value inside and out side the range, i am looking for a condition to change the button state to yellow, red , green accordingly of user input value. Now it always turns to be out of range and hitting 1st condition

Comment: what is uservalue ?

Comment: what errorr are you getting? for what input?

Comment: you just need one of the two conditions. I'd go for the second (check if it is between) but use `<=` and `>=` if you want to include the case when uservalue == min or max

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check a range of numbers in an if condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454198/check-a-range-of-numbers-in-an-if-condition)

Answer (score 2):

You are reading uservalue in as a string, you need to convert it to an int:

```
uservalue = parseInt(uservalue)
```

Also, this should be enough:

```
if(uservalue < min || uservalue > max ){
   alert("Error");
}
else {
   alert("success");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.value` will be a string value, not an integer. JavaScript's type-coercion is... complicated, so you'd be best-off doing explicit integer conversion with `parseInt` and `isNaN`:

```
var max = 50;
var min = 25;
var userValueStr = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
var userValueNum = parseInt( userValueStr );
if( !isNaN( userValueNum ) ) {

    if( min <= userValueNum && userValueNum < max ) {

        alert("Success");
    }
    else {

        alert("Outside of range");
    }
}
else {

    alert("Value was not a number.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would did it upside-down

```
if(uservalue>=min && uservalue<=max ){
    alert("In range");
}else if (uservalue>min){
    alert("Too high");
}else alert("Too low:);
alert("success");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(uservalue < min || uservalue > max ){
   alert("Error");
}
else {
   alert("success");
}
```

This must work.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
var uservalue = parseInt(document.getElementById("userinput").value);
```

or

```
if(+uservalue<min || +uservalue>max ){
    ...
}else if (+uservalue>min && +uservalue<max){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If input `type="text"` use with `parseInt()`

```js
function check(){
var uservalue = parseInt(document.getElementById("userinput").value);
var max = 50;
var min = 25;
if (uservalue>min && uservalue<max){
console.log("success");
}else 
  {
    console.log("Error");

  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="userinput" onchange="check()">
click me..!
```