# JavaScript function not passing my parameters to other function

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

I'm having a problem where I'm trying to send parameters from one function to another, the function that receives the parameters uses a switch statement to evaluate it and returns it but it just returns what ever variable I put into it instead of "senior Master" for example.
Here is the code I don't get what I'm doing wrong, just keep in mind I'm very new to coding maybe someone can give me some pointers. Thanks in advance.

```
function calculatexxx(x)  {
    let calculatexxx= x;
    switch (x) {
        case (x >= 2400):
            console.log("Senior Master");
            break;
        case (2399 > x > 2200):
            console.log("National Master");
            break;
        case (2199 > x> 2000):
            console.log("Expert");
            break;
        case (1999 > x> 1800):
            console.log("Class A");
            break;
        case (1799 > x> 1600):
            console.log("Class B");
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Error input not valid");

    return(x);

    }
}
function displayxxx() {
    console.log("Your Rank is: " + calculatexxx(2400)); // 

}
displayxxx();
```

Comment: Your `return` statement should be **outside** the `switch` block.

Comment: I suggest you look up 1. how `switch` statement is used. This is not the correct way - you are better of with an `if/else` chain. 2. how comparison operators work. `1799 > x> 1600` does not check if `x` is between `1799` and `1600`.

Comment: You really should not be using a switch for ranges. (and range check is not doing what you think it is doing. It is `((2399 > x) > 2200)`  so it would be `(true > 2200)` or `(false > 2200)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454198/check-if-a-value-is-within-a-range-of-numbers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just have a look to this expression

```
2399 > x > 2200
```

and take three values, like zero, 2300 (this should return `true`) and 10000.

The expression is executed in order of appearance, because of the same operator.

```
      x     2399 > x     value   value > 2200     yield     result
--------  ------------  -------  ------------  ----------  --------
      0   2399 >     0    true    true > 2200   1 > 2200     false
   2300   2399 >  2300    true    true > 2200   1 > 2200     false
 100000   2399 > 10000   false   false > 2200   0 > 2200     false
```

The final result is always `false`, because the first part returns a boolean value and the converted value is never greater than the last value.

*Conclusion*

Take two comparisons connected with [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()):

```
2399 > x && x > 2200
```

---

For taking a `switch` statement, you need to take the comparison value in the condition part and in the cases the other condition. And by returning directly, you could omit `break`, because the function ends with it.

```js
function calculate(x) {
    switch (true) {
        case x >= 2400: return "Senior Master";
        case x >= 2200: return "National Master";
        case x >= 2000: return "Expert";
        case x >= 1800: return "Class A";
        case x >= 1600: return "Class B";
    }
    return "Error input not valid";
}

function display() {
    console.log("Your Rank is: " + calculate(2400));
}

display();
```

Another solution could be to use continuing `if` statements and return early. This approach is better, because it does not missuse the original idea of `select` where two values have to be compared.

```js
function calculate(x) {
    if (x >= 2400) return "Senior Master";
    if (x >= 2200) return "National Master";
    if (x >= 2000) return "Expert";
    if (x >= 1800) return "Class A";
    if (x >= 1600) return "Class B";
    return "Error input not valid";
}

function display() {
    console.log("Your Rank is: " + calculate(2400));
}

display();
```

Comment: Why use a switch? ;)

Comment: Wow, I've never realised you could do that with a switch statement. Somehow it seems so wrong but at the same time awesome.

Comment: thanks very much this was very helpful, this is homework so i needed to use a switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you'll have to change your switch conditions from `1799 > x > 1600` to `1799 > x && x >= 1600`

Then instead of console.logging in the case itself, you should `return "Expert"` etc so the concatination in the function displayxxx actually does something.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this.

```
function calculatexxx(x)  {

        if (x >= 2400){
            console.log("Senior Master");
           }
           else if (2399 > x > 2200){
            console.log("National Master");
        }
        else if (2199 > x> 2000){
            console.log("Expert");
           }
        else if (1999 > x> 1800){
            console.log("Class A");
            }
        else if (1799 > x> 1600):
            console.log("Class B");
            }
        else{
            console.log("Error input not valid");
            }/////////////

    return(x);

    }
}
function displayxxx() {
    console.log("Your Rank is: " + calculatexxx(2400)); // 

}
displayxxx();
```

Comment: thanks for the help, i need to use a switch statement though.