# How can I check if a value is inside of a d3 scale range

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I use [d3's scaleLinear](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale). I want to filter values that are outside of the scale's domain.

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 15, 60, 700];

var scaleX = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([10, 100])
    .range([0, 200]);

// I need something like this:
scaleX.filter(arr)  // I want to get: [1, 15, 60]
```

My best solution is foreach all the values and check that the domain's min/max is less/greater than the given value. [Like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6454237/2506522)

Is there any more compact solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
var filteredArr = arr.filter(function(d) { 
    return d >= scaleX.domain()[0] && d <= scaleX.domain()[1]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply the filter method to the `arr` variable:

```
const filteredArray = arr.filter(function (value) { return ((value >= 10) && (value <= 100)) });
```

The `filteredArray` will contain only the values between 10 and 100 (inclusive).

You can read more about the `.filter` method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).