# About JS comparators linked behaviour (Abstract Relational Comparison)

Tags: javascript

Such code in JS `10 <= x <= 100` for *any* number `x` will always return `true`.

How is it called ? Why does it behave like this ? Where can I found some doc about it ?

Is `10 <= x && x <= 100` the shortest way to do things properly ?

Comment: Because it's evaluated as `(10 <= x) <= 100`, so `(true/false) <= 100`, and both `true` and `false` are `<= 100`.

Comment: It behaves like that because the `<=` operator is left-associative, so it's parsed as `(10 <= x) <= 100`. That's `true` because `10 <= x` returns a boolean value, and it'll be converted to either 0 or 1 in the comparison to 100. The documentation is the description of JavaScript expressions in *any* book or online reference for the language.

Comment: I think this question is much more general and applicable than the one it is marked a "duplicate" of this. (edit: I do agree somewhat with the duplicity... But not at all with the downvotes. It's a great question.)

Comment: @SidoShiro92 If you want to study the subject more. Transitivity and associativity of (comparison) operators are the terms to search for.

Comment: Unlike python JS doesn't evaluate `x < y < z` "mathematically".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454198/check-if-a-value-is-within-a-range-of-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Abstract Relational Comparison](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison)

`10 <= x` is going to be `true` or `false`.

Then `someBoolean <= 100` is going to cause the boolean to be converted to a number `1` or `0`.

Both `1` and `0` are less than `100`.

---

If you want to do **two** comparisons of a number then you need to explicitly make two comparisons and combine them with `&&`, not by simply mashing them together.

```
10 <= x && x <= 100
```