# compare list of IP ranges and short it to uniq ranges

Tags: javascript, serialization, comparison, ip-address

I have a list of IP ranges (taken from CIDR with script giving start address and end address) and I'm trying to get unique ranges (currently doing it by hand)

```
118.184.192.0-118.184.223.255
118.187.0.0-118.187.255.255
118.187.0.0-118.187.63.255
118.187.64.0-118.187.127.255
118.191.4.0-118.191.5.255
118.191.6.0-118.191.7.255
118.191.8.0-118.191.11.255
118.191.12.0-118.191.12.255
```

Line 3 `118.187.0.0-118.187.63.255` and line 4 `118.187.64.0-118.187.127.255` could be shortened to `118.187.0.0-118.187.127.255` because `63.255 (+1) is 64.0`

Could anyone give me a hint how can this be done by a script?

Current approach would be comparing Line3 2nd ip with Line4 1st ip by 'adding one' to first compared ip and checking if it is the same as second compared ip

```
// 118.187.63.255 (+1) = 118.187.64.0
var x = "118.187.63.255".split('.')
var y = "118.187.64.0".split('.')
var compare=0;
var thesamerange=0;
for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
  if(x[i] === y[i]){
    compare=0;
  }else{
    if((parseInt(x[i])+1)===parseInt(y[i])){
      compare=1 }
  }
  if(compare === 1){
    if( (x[i+1])==255 && (y[i+1])==0 ){
      thesamerange=1 }
  }
}
```

Is there an easier way to 'shorten the list' with unique ranges?

Comment: Do you also want ranges to be joined that overlap?

Comment: @OskarGrosser would be great, this is the end goal :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some hints that should help you to solve the problem yourself:

1. IP-addresses can be fully converted to numbers, and vice versa. ([Explanation for Java](https://mkyong.com/java/java-convert-ip-address-to-decimal-number/)).
2. Check whether ranges overlap (should be joined) by [whether one's endpoint is included in the other range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454198/check-if-a-value-is-within-a-range-of-numbers).

If you want a complete guide to how you *may* solve your issue, read on.

---

## Joining ranges

### What can be joined?

First we need to decide what ranges may be joined, which includes:

- Ranges that overlap:

  - Partly overlapping ranges.
  - Ranges where one is a subrange of the other.
- Ranges whose endpoints are immediate neighbours. (Ranges that are "touching".)

**Sidenote**: These two statements are equivalent:

1. Range `[a1, a2]` and `[b1, b2]` are neighbours.
2. Range `[a1, a2]` (partly) overlaps `[b1 - 1, b2 + 1]`. (Or vice versa.)

Overlapping ranges will still overlap after "extension" (statement 2). We will make use of this later on.

### Convert to simpler type

Now that we know the conditions for joining, we need to be able to check them.

For easier checking, we can convert the IP-addresses to integers:

- **From dot-notation**:
  Interpret IP-address as a base-256 4-"digit" number,
  where a digit is a dot-separated integer.
- **To dot-notation**:

  1. Parse number to a 8-digit hexadecimal number
     (with leading zeros, if necessary).
  2. Interpret every two base-16 digits as one base-256 digit.
  3. Parse the four base-256 digits to numbers.
  4. Join the numbers with dots.

```js
const ip = "192.168.0.1";

console.log("IP:", ip);
console.log("IP as number:", fromIp(ip));
console.log("IP after roundtrip:", toIp(fromIp(ip)));

function fromIp(ip) {
  const numbers = ip.split(".").map(split => Number(split));
  
  const ipAsNumber = numbers.reverse().reduce((total, number, i) => {
    return total + number * (256 ** i);
  }, 0);
  
  return ipAsNumber;
}
function toIp(number) {
  const numberInHex = number.toString(16).padStart(8, "0");
  
  const hexSplits = Array.from({length:4}, (v, i) => numberInHex.slice(i * 2, i * 2 + 2));
  const ipSplits = hexSplits.map(hex => parseInt(hex, 16));
  
  return ipSplits.join(".");
}
```

### How to check joinability

Realizing the checking may become easier to understand if we visualize the conditions:

[image: Four lines representing ranges (math.: intervals). Three lines fulfill the join conditions with a fourth line: 1. One is fully enclosed in the fourth. 2. One is partly overlapping the fourth. 3. One is immediately next to (touching) the fourth.]

Notice how the lines A, C, D may be joined with line B. Their commonality is (abstractly):

- The joinable line's left end is to the left of B's right end.
- The joinable line's right end is to the right of B's left end.

Or, in code:

```js
// Similar to the visualization
const rangeA = { from: 0, to: 3 };
const rangeB = { from: 2, to: 6 };
const rangeC = { from: 3, to: 4 };
const rangeD = { from: 5, to: 7 };

// Not "touching" rangeB
const unjoinableRange = { from: rangeB.to + 2, to: 10 };

console.log("Can join A & B?", isJoinable(rangeA, rangeB));
console.log("Can join C & B?", isJoinable(rangeC, rangeB));
console.log("Can join D & B?", isJoinable(rangeD, rangeB));

console.log("Joinable with unjoinable?", isJoinable(rangeB, unjoinableRange));

function isJoinable(range1, range2) {
  const maxDiff = 1; // Extend by this much; aforementioned stmt. 2 in "What can be joined?"
  return (range1.from - range2.to) <= maxDiff && (range2.from - range1.to) <= maxDiff;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100%!important}
```

### Joining

With the above sections we can easily find what ranges may be joined. But we still have to actually join them together.

For that, we can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to collect the (joined) ranges as follows:

```js
// Ranges A,B,C,D from before
const joinableRanges = [
  { from: 2, to: 6 },
  { from: 0, to: 3 },
  { from: 3, to: 4 },
  { from: 5, to: 7 }
];

const unjoinableRanges = [
  { from: 9, to: 10 },
  { from: -6, to: -2 }
];

const ranges = [...joinableRanges, ...unjoinableRanges];
const joinedRanges = reduceRanges(ranges);

console.log("Original:", ranges);
console.log("Reduced:", joinedRanges);

function reduceRanges(rangesToReduce) {
  const reducedRanges = rangesToReduce.reduce((ranges, range) => {
    let joinWith = range; // Start checking for current range
    const nextJoinableRange = () => ranges.find(r =>
      r !== joinWith // Avoid joining with self
      && isJoinable(r, joinWith)
    );
    
    let joinableRange = nextJoinableRange();
    
    if (!joinableRange) {
      // No joinable range was found; add current range
      ranges.push(range);
      return ranges;
    }
    
    // A joinable range was found
    
    do {
      // Remove joinable range; will be replaced with joined range
      const index = ranges.indexOf(joinableRange);
      ranges.splice(index, 1);
      
      // Add joined range
      const joinedRange = {
        from: Math.min(joinableRange.from, joinWith.from),
        to: Math.max(joinableRange.to, joinWith.to)
      };
      ranges.push(joinedRange);
      
      // Continue with (checking for) joining
      joinWith = joinedRange;
    } while (joinableRange = nextJoinableRange());
    
    return ranges;
  }, []);
  
  return reducedRanges;
}

function isJoinable(range1, range2) {
  return (range1.from - range2.to) <= 1 && (range2.from - range1.to) <= 1;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100%!important}
```

### Finally

Putting everything together:

1. Convert from IP-address ranges to number ranges.
2. Join ranges:

   1. If current range is unjoinable, collect.
   2. Otherwise, join with joinable range.
   3. Replace joinable range with joined range.
   4. Repeat for joined range from 2.
3. Convert from number ranges

```js
const ipRanges = [
  { from: "118.184.192.0", to: "118.184.223.255" },
  { from: "118.187.0.0", to: "118.187.255.255" },
  { from: "118.187.0.0", to: "118.187.63.255" },
  { from: "118.187.64.0", to: "118.187.127.255" },
  { from: "118.191.4.0", to: "118.191.5.255" },
  { from: "118.191.6.0", to: "118.191.7.255" },
  { from: "118.191.8.0", to: "118.191.11.255" },
  { from: "118.191.12.0", to: "118.191.12.255" }
];

const numberRanges = ipRanges.map(({ from, to }) =>
  ({ from: fromIp(from), to: fromIp(to) })
);

const joinedRanges = reduceRanges(numberRanges);

const joinedIpRanges = joinedRanges.map(({ from, to }) =>
  ({ from: toIp(from), to: toIp(to) })
);

console.log("IP-ranges:", ipRanges );
console.log("Reduced IP-ranges:", joinedIpRanges);

function reduceRanges(rangesToReduce) {
  const reducedRanges = rangesToReduce.reduce((ranges, range) => {
    let joinWith = range;
    const nextJoinableRange = () => ranges.find(r =>
      r !== joinWith && isJoinable(r, joinWith)
    );
    
    let joinableRange = nextJoinableRange();
    
    if (!joinableRange) {
      ranges.push(range);
      return ranges;
    }
    
    do {
      const index = ranges.indexOf(joinableRange);
      ranges.splice(index, 1);
      
      const joinedRange = {
        from: Math.min(joinableRange.from, joinWith.from),
        to: Math.max(joinableRange.to, joinWith.to)
      };
      ranges.push(joinedRange);
      
      joinWith = joinedRange;
    } while (joinableRange = nextJoinableRange());
    
    return ranges;
  }, []);
  
  return reducedRanges;
}

function isJoinable(range1, range2) {
  return (range1.from - range2.to) <= 1 && (range2.from - range1.to) <= 1;
}

function fromIp(ip) {
  const numbers = ip.split(".").map(split => Number(split));

  const ipAsNumber = numbers.reverse().reduce((total, number, i) => {
    return total + number * (256 ** i);
  }, 0);

  return ipAsNumber;
}
function toIp(number) {
  const numberInHex = number.toString(16).padStart(8, "0");

  const hexSplits = Array.from({length:4}, (v, i) => numberInHex.slice(i * 2, i * 2 + 2));
  const ipSplits = hexSplits.map(hex => parseInt(hex, 16));

  return ipSplits.join(".");
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100%!important}
```

---

This answer includes only how to join IP-address ranges.

As apparent in your answer, you receive the ranges in a specific format (ranges as `start-end`, one per line). You may still want to convert from that format to some easier-to-work-with object. See this as an exercise!

Comment: wow, niiiice explain!
I think I will have to modify CIDR to range script to join ranges there (less code, one step instead of two)